# Email not send with godady professional mail

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to send mail using godady smtp. My email and password is correct but mail is not sending.

**My smtp setting**

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtpout.secureserver.net
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=support@example.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=examplepassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_TO=support@example.com
```

This credentials is working for localhost but not working for live server. i also try with port number 25, 587.

i dont know what is worng.

Comment: If you're having issues with a specific service or how to configure it, I would recommend that you contact their support.

Comment: i also contact with godady support team but he is was recommended above configuration.

Comment: If they told you to use a specific configuration for their service and it doesn't work, you should contact them again and say that. We don't have more knowledge about their services than they do. Is the live server also hosted at GoDaddy? If yes, then you def. need to contact them. If no, then it might be that hosting service that blocks you from connecting to GoDaddy's SMTP (and you need to contact that hosting company).

Comment: Godaddy definitely blocks SMTP, you should use a third party service like mailgun.  (unless you use GoDaddy Relay servers) https://ie.godaddy.com/help/send-form-mail-using-an-smtp-relay-server-953